# How to structured data in custom WebAPI?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, webapi

I have created custom webapi using https://www.demacmedia.com/extending-magento-2-rest-web-api/
This is the code that I am using:

```
<?php
namespace Panda\WebService\Model\Resource;
use Panda\WebService\Api\WebServiceRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnectionFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Address;
/**
 * Class WebServiceRepository
 * @package Panda\WebService\Model
 */
class WebServiceRepository implements WebServiceRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ResourceConnectionFactory
     */
    protected $_resourceConnection;
    /**
     * @var ProductCollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollection;
    /**
     * @var CategoryFactory
     */
    protected $_category;
    /**
     * @var CategoryFactory
     */
    protected $_customer;
    /**
     * @var Address
     */
    protected $_address;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_jsonHelper;
    /**
     * WebServiceRepository constructor.
     *
     * @param ResourceConnectionFactory $_resourceConnection
     */
    public function __construct(
        ResourceConnectionFactory $_resourceConnection, 
        ProductCollectionFactory $_productCollection, 
        CategoryFactory $_category,
        CustomerFactory $_customer,
        Address $address,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
    )
    {
        $this->_resourceConnection = $_resourceConnection;
        $this->_productCollection = $_productCollection;
        $this->_category = $_category;
        $this->_customer = $_customer;
        $this->_address = $address;
        $this->_jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCatalogProductCount()
    {
        return $this->_productCollection->create()->getSize();
    }
    /**
     * @param $categoryId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCategoryProductCount($categoryId)
    {
        $size = 0;
        $category = $this->_category->create()->load($categoryId);
        if (isset($category) && !empty($category)) {
            $size = $category->getProductCollection()->getSize();
        }
        return $size;
    }

    /**
     * @param $customerId
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCustomer($customerId)
    {
        $customerData = array();
        $customerModel = $this->_customer->create();
        $customer = $customerModel->load($customerId);
        if (isset($customer) && !empty($customer)) {
            $customerData['UserName'] = $customer->getEmail();
            $customerData['IDClient'] = $customer->getId();
            $customerData['ID'] = $customer->getId();
            $customerData['SuccExterne'] = $customer->getData('succexterne');
            $customerData['LastName'] = $customer->getLastname();
            $customerData['FirstName'] = $customer->getFirstname();
            $customerData['BirthDate'] = $customer->getDob();
            $customerData['Email'] = $customer->getEmail();
            $customerData['Language'] = $customer->getData('language');
            $customerData['Gender'] = $customer->getGender();
            $customerData['ConsentementC28'] = $customer->getData('consentementc28');
            $customerData['CardNo'] = $customer->getData('cardno');
            $customerData['Externe'] = $customer->getData('externe');
            $updateTimeStamp = strtotime($customer->getUpdatedAt());
            $customerData['ModificationDate'] = date('Y-m-d', $updateTimeStamp);
            $childId = $customer->getData('child_customer_id');

            // Get Address
            $billingID =  $customer->getDefaultBilling();
            $shippingID =  $customer->getDefaultShipping();

            if(!empty($billingID) && isset($billingID)) {
                $billingAddress = $this->_address->load($billingID);
                $streetAddress = implode(', ', $billingAddress->getStreet());
                $customerData['Address'] = $streetAddress;
                $customerData['City'] = $billingAddress->getCity();
                $customerData['Province'] = $billingAddress->getRegion();
                $customerData['Country'] = $billingAddress->getCountryId();
                $customerData['PostalCode'] = $billingAddress->getPostcode();
                $customerData['Phone'] = $billingAddress->getTelephone();
            } elseif (!empty($shippingID) && isset($shippingID)) {
                $shippingAddress = $this->_address->load($shippingID);
                $streetAddress = implode(', ', $shippingAddress->getStreet());
                $customerData['Address'] = $streetAddress;
                $customerData['City'] = $shippingAddress->getCity();
                $customerData['Province'] = $shippingAddress->getRegion();
                $customerData['Country'] = $shippingAddress->getCountryId();
                $customerData['PostalCode'] = $shippingAddress->getPostcode();
                $customerData['Phone'] = $shippingAddress->getTelephone();
            }

            // Get Child Customer
            if($childId) {
                $childCustomer = $customerModel->load($childId);
                $customerData['CHILDREN'] = [
                                                'ID' => $childId,
                                                'ParentID' => $customerId,
                                                'LastName' => $childCustomer->getLastname(),
                                                'FirstName' => $childCustomer->getFirstname(),
                                                'Gender' => $childCustomer->getGender(),
                                                'BirthDate' => $childCustomer->getDob(),
                                                'Deleted' => false
                                            ];
            }

        }
        return $customerData;
        // echo $this->_jsonHelper->jsonEncode($customerData);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

When I return single data then there is no problem, but when I return json or array then it doesn't format that in proper json. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to return complex types from your custom web API endpoint, specify reference to data interface as your return type.

```
/**
 * @param $customerId
 * @return \YourNamespace\Api\CustomInterface
 */
public function getCustomer($customerId)
```

Where `\YourNamespace\Api\CustomerInterface` should be similar to

`\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface` in core, it should contain corresponding setters and getters for every field. Every field may in its turn reference scalar type, another data interface or an array of scalar types or data interfaces.